# Jenkins does not show some builds log and failed builds in history

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, gerrit

We have updated our Jenkins CI tool to updated version number is: 1.596.1. The problem is, for some projects, we cannot see the build console log. When we try to see the log, Jenkins responds with 404 error page.

Also, when this problem occurs in a particular job, we have examined that, failed builds are not be shown in the build history list in the job page. Even though we see that there is build from the gerrit history, when I click on the job with the specified ID, I again get the 404 error.

We are using Jenkins with Git/Gerrit, and most builds are triggered from the Gerrit review system.

New information: Jobs that have this problem have also the **inconsistent timestamp** problem. 
It seems that this problem also occurs when Jenkins job is triggered by a **patchset creation/merge** in Gerrit review system.

What may be the root cause for this problem? Is it the version we're using or some other factor?

Answer (score 1):

This is a persistent problem with Jenkins. A restart, which you can do from the front page when you're authenticated, is the fix. Visit

```
https://yoursite/jenkins/quietDown
```

to restart the instance.